# Which c# class should be used when parsing XML from a remote URI?

Tags: c#, xml

I've read that the XmlReader class is preferred over XmlDocument because of the memory overhead that you get when loading the entire file in memory. However, does this still hold true when we are trying to parse a xml file from a remote source over the internet?

I'm guessing that the whole file is downloaded in our memory and we do not send a http request for each an every line of the file when we use XmlReader.Read(). So in this case, does it matter, in terms of performance, which one of the classes we choose to use?

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is how large the document can possibly be.  For most people, one can expect its max size to be sufficiently small so as to not have to worry about memory and thus can leverage the easier-to-use APIs of `XmlDocument` and, moreover, `XDocument`.

Comment: This is a good question - I hope someone with some experience using either of them can speak to their inner-workings.

Comment: I'm currently testing with a file that has about 100k lines, but in theory they can be any number of times bigger. That brought me to the conclusion that I normally should be using XmlReader, but I'm not entirely certain that there is any difference when my goal is to only read the entire file and use some of the values from it for some other task.

Comment: With XmlDocument when you load the file the entire xml is parsed which takes a lot of resources on a large file.  XmlReader on reads only a portion of the xml file at one time taking a lot less resources.